# auditpol for windows server 2003?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I want to do this for 2003 version of Windows:

```
Auditpol /set /category:* /success:disable
Auditpol /set /category:* /failure:disable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auditpol was introduced in Windows Server 2008/Vista. There is no such tool for Windows Server 2003.

Alternatives may be to edit the local security policy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.
The precursor to auditpol.exe on Windows Server 2003 is auditusr.exe.

See details on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875806.aspx) (watch for misspellings!) and on [the MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spatdsg/archive/2005/04/01/404671.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use *auditpol* from the Windows resource kit (for 2000/2003/XP). The syntax is slightly different but it achieves the same result. You can also use it to set the audit policy on remote machines and even works in Windows 8. The only drawback is that is doesn't seem to allow you to change sub categories, you have to change a whole category at a time where the latest *auditpol* is a bit more powerful there.

All the individual tools are available on this site: http://www.petri.co.il/download_free_reskit_tools.htm

Download *auditpol* here (single executable in a zip file): http://www.dynawell.com/download/reskit/microsoft/win2000/auditpol.zip

To disable everything like you are doing in your example, run the following command using this version:

```
Auditpol.exe \\localhost /enable /system:none /logon:none /object:none /privilege:none /process:none /policy:none /sam:none
```